# Flexslider image size - automatic adjust to fluid width?

Tags: css, image, layout, slider, flexslider

I've installed the basic version of Flexslider. I've removed the css related to div ID="main", so that the slider can stretch across my page.

However, the images don't adjust according to the new width.

[This is what I mean.](http://adam.com.sa/flex.png)

I changed the width property for:

```
.flexslider .slides img
```

This does change the width, but the images still do not automatically align themselves to start on the left where the slider starts. There remains a kind of image overlap.

What needs to be changed in the CSS to have them aligned? Does FlexSlider only work with fixed image sizes, and not a fluid layout?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was wrapped a span with a class to the image tag

```
<span class="className"><img src="images/slideImage-1.jpg"></span>
```

Then in the CSS I added

```
.flexslider .slides .className img{
width: 244px;
```

}

Hope that helps